# onPostExecute clash when using AsyncTask - android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I can't understand what is happening here. The `ide` throws this message `onPostExecute(Bitmap)' in 'Anonymous class derived from android.os.AsyncTask' clashes with 'onPostExecute(Result)' in 'android.os.AsyncTask'; attempting to use incompatible return type`:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View[] v = {convertView};
        final Bitmap[] mBitmap = new Bitmap[1];
        final Object that = this.resources;
        View view = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... args) {
                try {
                    mBitmap[0] = drawableFromUrl(activity.getString(R.string.test_url));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return mBitmap[0];
            }

            @Override
            protected View onPostExecute(Bitmap mBitmap) {
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable((Resources) that, mBitmap);

                final Feed item = feed_items.get(position);

                if (v[0] == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi =
                            (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v[0] = vi.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                }

                if (item != null) {
                    v[0].findViewById(R.id.v1).setBackground(d);
                    v[0].findViewById(R.id.v2).setBackground(d);
                }
                return v[0];
            }

        }.execute((Void) null);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: You have to return void from onPostExecute() as far as I know.

Comment: onPostExecute does not return anything, and the whole idea of an asynctask is to be ... async, meaning you cannot receive the result just after you called it.

Comment: sure but if I make it return `void`, and make `getView` returns `return v[0]`, I get this `ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2179)`

Comment: Hint: There's more than one problem in the code. Fix one, find the next one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using getView() in a custom adapater.

But you can't return from an onPostExecute(), so try to inflate the view right away.

Setup the AsyncTask to download the BPM and update the view, but return it normally from getView() even though the data isn't there yet. Once the Async completes it will be there.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v1 = convertView;
    final Bitmap[] mBitmap = new Bitmap[1];
    final Object that = this.resources;

    final View v;
    if (v1 == null) {
         LayoutInflater vi =
              (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         v = vi.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    }
    else {
         v = v1;
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... args) {
            try {
                mBitmap[0] = drawableFromUrl(activity.getString(R.string.test_url));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mBitmap[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap mBitmap) {
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable((Resources) that, mBitmap);

            final Feed item = feed_items.get(position);
            v.findViewById(R.id.v1).setBackground(d);
            v.findViewById(R.id.v2).setBackground(d);
        }

    }.execute((Void) null);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer, but it does not address the question.

Comment: "But you can't return from an onPostExecute()" but..., the main problem he has is where he is inflating the view. I changed the code so its inflated outside the AsyncTask, eliminating the need for return value from onPostExecute (which doesn't work anyways).

Comment: OK.  I like the edited version much better.  It makes it clear WHY you are answering the question he didn't ask.

Answer (score 0):

The return type from onPostExecute should be void.

See:   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29

Comment: sure but if I make it return `void`, and make `getView` returns `return v[0]`, I get this `ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2179)`

Comment: the return type from AsyncTask.execute is a reference to the AsyncTask object itself. Most often this will return before the task actually executes (no guarantees either way!)  Therefore trying to get data from the AsyncTask object is a bad idea.  You need to rethink what you are trying to achieve.